# What is the punishment for kissing someone outside of marriage?

Tags: punishment, kissing

Is it true that we're not allowed to kiss somebody before getting married to her/him according to Islam? If it is, what is the punishment for that?

Comment: For sure it is a big sin. we should always avoid it. in islam, the ruler of islamic country can decide that what punishment to give for kissing, may be 10 lashes.

Answer (score 1):

About kissing a foreign woman i found this Hadith:

> Ibn Mas'ud (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: A man kissed a
>   woman. So he came to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) and informed him about
>   it. Then Allah revealed this Ayah: "And perform the Salat, between the
>   two ends of the day and in some hours of the night. Verily, the good
>   deeds efface the evil deeds (i.e., minor sins)." (11:114) The man
>   asked the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) whether this applies to him only. The
>   Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "It applies to all of my Ummah."
>
> [Shaih al-Bukhari & Msulim]

and this [Fatwa](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=23208) in Arabic.

And don't forget a sincere repentance and expiation with real regretting and turn the sins into good deeds like praying, fasting,..., doing good things,helping: Being a good muslim and not redoing what those sins ...is necessary!

And Allah knows best!